# Remove all lines except D

Tags: shell-script

I have scenario where my three huge files `Test.txt` , `Test1.txt` and `Test2.txt` has following details.

```
H|||||||||||||||||||||||
D||||||||||||||||||||||||
D|||||||||||||||||||||||
H|||||||||||||||||||||
D||||||||||||||||||||||||
D||||||||||||||||||||||||
T||||||||||||||||||||||||
```

I have to delete all except D lines.
It should look like below in all my three files.(more than 10 GB)

```
D||||||||||||||||||||||||
D|||||||||||||||||||||||
D||||||||||||||||||||||||
D||||||||||||||||||||||||
```

So after retaining only D's lines in `Test.txt`, `Test2.txt` and `Test3.txt`, 
I have to merge those into new file.

I have done the above operation using sed.

```
sed '/^\('D'\)|/!d' $Filename.txt >>  $NewFilename.txt
```

But because of huge file its taking very long time.

Can we do this operation using any other command in efficient way?

Comment: Personally, I would've written it as `sed -ne /^D/p'`, but by and large, if you don't know any other constraints on your file (fixed line length, for example), your task involves scanning the 10G for '\nD' no matter what.

Comment: Of course you could try running this in parallel using `split` on the files. Just be patient, sit out the time (an hour or so?), and do something useful in the meantime. I have script/programs running for hours, days, weeks or even months. I don't wait until they're done :)

Comment: Obligatory [xkcd](http://xkcd.com/303/)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
cat Test.txt Test2.txt Test3.txt | LC_ALL=C grep '^D' > newfile.txt
```

Or:

```
for file in Test.txt Test2.txt Test3.txt; do
  LC_ALL=C grep '^D' < "$file"
done > newfile.txt
```

Or if your `grep` like GNU `grep` supports the `-h` option (to avoid printing file names):

```
LC_ALL=C grep -h '^D' Test.txt Test2.txt Test3.txt > newfile.txt
```

By using `LC_ALL=C` we avoid `grep` trying to parse UTF-8 data. By using `^D`, `grep` will only look at the first character of each line. `grep`, especially GNU `grep` is generally a lot faster than `sed`.

Comment: I have tried above command , it works pretty good for huge files.
But issue is when i run above command for multiple files like above
LC_ALL=C grep '^D' Test.txt Test2.txt Test3.txt > newfile.txt
Its removing every thing except D, but for each lines its adding respective file name.
Test.txt: D|||||||||||||||||||||||
Test.txt: D|||||||||||||||||||||||
Test2.txt D||||||||||||||||||||||||
Test3.txt D|||||||||||||||||||||||

So How to get rid of file names????

Comment: @UNIXbest. Oops, sorry, answer updated.

Comment: Hello, IF just want to delete first and last lines of the files and merge into single file.
How can we achieve this through LC_ALL=C grep command??

Comment: @UNIXbest, that's a different question, and the answer would not involve `grep` since `grep` is to print the lines matching given pattern.

Comment: ok i got it. Do we have any other command to remove first and last line of multiple files and merge it into single file.

Answer (score 3):

This will most likely be an I/O bound operation (as opposed to CPU-bound), so even if you don't use a regexp-engine like:

```
grep -F 'D|' Test.txt Test2.txt Test3.txt
```

it will take a long time, simply because the file has to be tokenised into lines and then scanned for the pattern.

If this is a one off thing and you don't mind coding, you could `mmap(3)` the whole file into memory and use `memmem(3)`:

```
char *p;
if ((p = memmem(file, size, "\nD|", 3)) != NULL) {
        /* massage the line, i.e. find the next '\n'
         * and print the region between p+1 and the
         * next '\n' */
}
```

where `file` is the pointer to the mmapped buffer and `size` is the file size.  (If this turns out to be helpful, I'm happy to elaborate more).

This approach will still take some time (as your problem is I/O-bound) but at least you'd save the time to tokenise the file into lines.

Comment: you are looking for "D|" *anywhere* in the line, not at the beginning. change `grep -F 'D|'` to `grep -F '^D'` (which will also speed things up, as grep knows it can just go to the next line without testing the rest of it)

Comment: @OlivierDulac That won't work, `grep -F` allows only literal strings, and yes I'm aware of this caveat, I assumed the OP's files would all look like their example and not have a `D|` in the middle of a line.

Comment: then just `grep '^D'`, which will speed things up still ^^